# ValueError: Can't specify both mapper_raw and mapper in Python

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

I am trying to read `fna` file with `mrjob` in Python.

This is my `load_read.py` program, all of the code can work correctly without using `mrjob`.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
import re
from operator import itemgetter 
import sys

def format_read(read):
    z = re.split('[|={,]+', read.description)
    return read.seq, z[3]

class LoadMetaRead(MRJob):

    def mapper_raw(self, file_path, file_uri):
        from Bio import SeqIO
        from Bio.Seq import Seq

        seqs = list(SeqIO.parse(file_path, type='fna'))

        is_paired_end = False
        if len(seqs) > 2 and seqs[0].id[-1:] != seqs[1].id[-1:]:
            is_paired_end = True

        label_list = dict()
        label_index = 0
        
        for i in range(0, len(seqs), 2 if is_paired_end else 1):
            read, label = format_read(seqs[i])
            if is_paired_end:
                read2, _ = format_read(seqs[i + 1])
                read += read2
            
            if label not in label_list:
                label_list[label] = label_index
                label_index += 1

            yield str(i), str(read), str(label_list[label])            

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield 'read', line

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, values

    combiner = reducer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoadMetaRead.run()
```

Example of the data file `R4.fna`:

```
>r1.1 |SOURCES={GI=15668172,fw,1146130-1146958}|ERRORS={52_1:A,78_1:G,78_2:G,78_3:G,641_1:G}|SOURCE_1="Methanocaldococcus jannaschii DSM 2661 chromosome" (392b1054a4bf536ea1cc349545ace50120973c3a)
AAACCCTCTTCCACGAACCCTCTTGAAAATCCCCCACATCCACAAAATAAATCAAATAAATTTCA
ACATTATCACCAAAAGGGTAAAAGGTTATTTAAAAAATAAAATAAATTTAAAAATTTAAATTAAA
TACCAAAAAAGCCAAATAACTTATTGTGATTCTTGAGCTTTCTTTAACTCTGCCTTCATATCTTG
ATAGACTTTAGTCCATTTTAATTTTCTTGGATTTCTTCCCATTCTGTAGCTTTTCTCACATTTGG
ATGAGCAGAAATATAATACAGTCCCATCTTTTTCTACGACCATTTTTCCTTTTCCTGGCTCAATT
TCATAACCACAAAAGCTGCATGTTCTCCATTCTGGCATAGCTATCCCCCTTTAATAGTGTTTCAG
TGATTTTAAAATAATTTAAGATTAAATTATTTATCTTCTTCTGTCTAATGGTCTTGCTTCTCTCT
CTGTTTCTCTTAACATAATAATGTCTCCAACTTTAACTGGACCTTTAACGTTTCTAACTAAAACT
CTTCCAGTATCTTTTCCACCTAAGATTTTACATCTAACTTGTATAATTCCTCCAGTAACCCCTGT
TCTACCAATGACTTCAATAACTTCAGCAGCTACTGCTTCCTTATAAACAAATTCATCTTCCGATC
CTCATCACCTAATATTAATGAAGGTTTAAAATTTATAAAAAAGTTAGTAGTAGTGTTTCATAATT
TATATAATAATAACTATATACTATTGATTGATGGTTAAATAGCGTTCTAATAATTTACTGCTTCA
AAACATTTACCTTTTCAATTAATACCTTTAACTCTTCAGCATCTCCTTCGTTG
>r2.1 |SOURCES={GI=15668172,bw,239211-239971}|ERRORS={113:-,217_1:C,281_1:G,627_1:G,717_1:T}|SOURCE_1="Methanocaldococcus jannaschii DSM 2661 chromosome" (392b1054a4bf536ea1cc349545ace50120973c3a)
TAGCATGTAAATCCCTTATTTCTTAATTTCTCCCAGAATTATTTCTATTGCTTTATCAACTGCCT
TGGCAACCTCTTCAGACAACCCTGGTTTTATGTCTGGCATTGTAAATTTTTACCTTGACAACCAA
TAACCACGACTTCTATGCCTTTATTATGTAAATCTTTGAGAAATGGGGCTAATGGAACGTTATGG
GCATCGAAAGAATATTTTTTAACTATTCGGTAATTCATCAACATCTATCTTTTTTATTGTTCCAG
GTTCTAAATCAAAATCAATGGCGATCAACAACAATAATCTTTTTTATATCTTCATCAACCAACGT
CATTAAATAGTATGCTCCACTTGCCCCAGCATCTATAACTTCAACGTTATCTGGCAAGTTCATTT
TTTCTAATTTGCTAACAACCTCACATCCAAAGCCATCATCTCCAAACAACAGATTTCCACAACCA
ACAATTAATATATCCTTCTTTTTCATTTTATCACTTATTTAGCATTTCTTTATATTTTTTAGCCT
CTTCTTTAGGATTTTGTGATTGATAGATTGCCCTTCCAACAATGACGTAATCATTCTCATCTAAA
ATATTTAAAATATCCTCAATCTTCCCTCCCTGAGCTCCGACTCCGTGGTGTTATTACTGGCAATT
CTGCAATTTCTTTAATTTCTTTAAGCCTTTCAGGCCTTGTTGATGGAGCAACTATAGCATCAACT
TTTAGTTTTTTTAGCCATCTCTGACAATTTATCTGCTATTGGCTGTAG
```

When I run the program with this command:

```
python load_read.py R4.fna
```

It raises this error:

```
ValueError: Can't specify both mapper_raw and mapper
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that I cannot define both `mapper_raw()` and `mapper`. I only need to define one of them.
I used `mapper_raw()` because I read a whole file, not line by line.

```py
class LoadMetaRead(MRJob):

    def mapper_raw(self, file_path, file_uri):
        from Bio import SeqIO
        from Bio.Seq import Seq

        seqs = list(SeqIO.parse(file_path, 'fasta'))

        is_paired_end = False
        if len(seqs) > 2 and seqs[0].id[-1:] != seqs[1].id[-1:]:
            is_paired_end = True

        label_list = dict()
        label_index = 0
        
        for i in range(0, len(seqs), 2 if is_paired_end else 1):
            read, label = format_read(seqs[i])
            if is_paired_end:
                read2, _ = format_read(seqs[i + 1])
                read += read2
            
            if label not in label_list:
                label_list[label] = label_index
                label_index += 1

            yield None, (str(read), str(label_list[label]))

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        for value in values:
            yield key, str(value)
```

This code work as expected.